# How to create an XML File?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to create an XML File at runtime and how to add attributes?? And how to save it in isolated storage??

Thanks,
Balaram.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this MSDN article: [How to: Save to and Load from Isolated Storage with LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838189%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are useful extensions to standard XmlSerializer such as XmlIgnore attribute. For example if you have IsDirty property, you don't want to store it. This code achieves it:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool IsDirty { get; set; }
```